# Drawing thousands of rects quickly

Tags: qt, drawing, scene

What is the proper way to draw thousands of `rects` in QT (around 100,000 or more)?

I tried:

- Simple with `paintEvent()` of `QWidget`.
- Drawing objects to `QImage` then this image to `QWidget`.
- Using `QGraphicsScene` (maybe I didn't use it properly, I just added `rects` to scene)

Every time drawing was really slow and I don't have more ideas on how to do this (maybe with opengl/directx but this doesn't sound like a good idea). I know that there exist applications that do that so there should be some way.

EDIT:

I wonder how `drawRects()` work? Is there a chance that filling some `uchar*` array and passing it to `QImage` will be better?

Comment: Rule N1 - draw only what's visible. You don't mean to tell me you have 100k rectangles on the screen at the same time?

Comment: Also, it really depends on what you are actually doing, ok, you are drawing 100k rectangles, but why, for what purpose, what is the practical application?

Comment: Sometimes there can be (and I saw applications that can do this but probably they weren't in qt)
This is for profiler, so there can be a lot of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution which I found:

Create array of `uint32_t` which can contain all pixels of `widget`, fill it using `memcpy()`. Create `QImage` with this array and use `drawImage()` to show it.
It can have some optimization like (for profiler) merging `rects` that are continues ( start time second is equal to end of first ). Don't draw `rects` that are out of time bounds. Maybe skip too small `rects`.
For drawing things like text, tool tips you can still use `Qt` functions.
For alpha blending in simplest case you can just take existing values, blend them in loop and write blended values or maybe use `SIMD` for this.

Of course for more complex shapes it will get harder to draw but still, I think, it will be faster than using `Qt` functions.

Answer (score 0):

The first trick is to do the drawing in a separate thread onto a `QImage`, then pass that into the main thread. This won't make it quicker, but it'll make it not block the GUI thread.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/threaded-paint-36748972
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtConcurrent>

class Widget : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   QImage m_image;
   bool m_pendingRender { false };
   Q_SIGNAL void hasNewRender(const QImage &);
   // Must be thread-safe, we can't access the widget directly!
   void paint() {
      QImage image{2048, 2048, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied};
      image.fill(Qt::white);
      QPainter p(&image);
      for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
         QColor c{rand() % 256, rand() % 256, rand() % 256};
         p.setBrush(c);
         p.setPen(c);
         p.drawRect(rand() % 2048, rand() % 2048, rand() % 100, rand() % 100);
      }
      emit hasNewRender(image);
   }
   void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
      QPainter p(this);
      p.drawImage(0, 0, m_image);
   }
public:
   Widget(QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
      this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
      setMinimumSize(200, 200);
      connect(this, &Widget::hasNewRender, this, [this](const QImage & img) {
         m_image = img;
         m_pendingRender = false;
         update();
      });
      refresh();
   }
   Q_SLOT void refresh() {
      if (!m_pendingRender) {
         m_pendingRender = true;
         QtConcurrent::run([this] { paint(); });
      }
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   Widget w;
   QPushButton button{"Refresh", &w};
   button.connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, &w, [&w]{ w.refresh(); });
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

As a separate concern, you can then split the drawing across multiple parallel jobs, by clipping each job's painter to a sub-area of the shared image, and  noting that fully clipped rectangle draws are no-ops, and partially clipped ones will only fill the pixels they affect.