# Qt - using QString::arg to align text into columns

Tags: c++, string, qt, format

I'm formatting a string using QString::arg, and I need the string to be formatted in columns. For example:

```
78.0    78.0    78.0
0.0     0.0     78.0
69.0    56.0    0.0
```

Right now I'm using`d += QString("%1").arg("78.0", -50, ' ');` for each column then `d += '\n'` for a new row.

The only problem is that the space character isn't the same width as the digits, so things become misaligned:

[image: misalignment]

All I want to know is how can I align the text into columns? Thanks.

Comment: What is that screenshot from? In other words, how are you displaying the text? Why not using a monospace font?

Comment: You're asking the wrong thing. It's not about `QString`, it's about whatever you use to display text: it must support the alignment you desire. Please edit the question to show a self-contained example of how you're doing it - it  should be <20 lines long, a single `main.cpp`.

Comment: @peppe Ahh, I wasn't aware monospace fonts existed. How can I get my QTableWidget to use a monospace font?

Comment: Nevermind, after a quick google search i was able to use a monospace font. Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: This makes no sense. You don't need to use whitespace to align columns in a `QTableWidget`. What are you doing exactly? A `QTableWidget` or `QTableView` can display perfectly aligned columns! Please tell us *exactly* what you're trying to do first. Probably the *how* is completely wrong.

Comment: @KubaOber Please don't say something doesn't make sense just because you don't understand it. I never Said I was using a table, I'm just printing a QString to a QPlainTextEdit. All I'm doing is creating a string (First line in my post) and was wondering how to format it properly. The monospace font was the issue, so it's all OK now. Nothing is "_completely_ wrong" at all

Comment: You don't need a monospace font to align text in columns in a `QTextEdit`. Instead of using a `QPlainTextEdit` and doing alignment as if you were on a green screen, you can leverage the rich text and get explicitly aligned tables etc. Besides you *did* say that you were using a `QTableWidget`.

Comment: @KubaOber If you know how to align text in columns without a monospace font in a `QPlainTextEdit` please enlighten me.

Comment: @KubaOber oh, in the comment i guess I did say that, that was a typo. Anyways, I'm loading in A LOT of text, and loading it in to a QTextEdit takes a long while to load it in. A QPlainTextEdit was much more efficient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115236/discussion-between-picklechips-and-kuba-ober).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `QTextEdit` and its rich text layout capabilities. You can then generate an html table programmatically:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/textedit-columns-37949301
#include <QtWidgets>

template <typename It, typename F>
QString toTable(It begin, It end, int columns, F && format, 
                const QString & attributes = QString()) {
   if (begin == end) return QString();
   QString output = QStringLiteral("<table %1>").arg(attributes);
   int n = 0;
   for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
      if (!n) output += "<tr>";
      output += "<td>" + format(*begin) + "</td>";
      if (++n == columns) {
         n = 0;
         output += "</tr>";
      }
   }
   output += "</table>";
   return output;
}
```

If you're loading a lot of data into a `QTextEdit`, you can create a `QTextDocument` in a separate thread, fill it there, and then transfer it to `QTextEdit`:

```
#include <QtConcurrent>

void setHtml(QTextEdit * edit, const QString & html) {
  QtConcurrent::run([=]{
    // runs in a worker thread
    auto doc = new QTextDocument;
    doc->setHtml(html);
    doc->moveToThread(edit->thread());
    QObject src;
    src.connect(&src, &QObject::destroyed, qApp, [=]{
      // runs in the main thread
      doc->setParent(edit);
      edit->setDocument(doc);
    });
  });
}
```

In a similar manner it's possible to relegate the `QTextEdit`'s rendering to a worker thread as well, although that's a matter I'd have to address in a separate question. The approach would be akin to [the one in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36751827/1329652).

Let's put it to use:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   double const table[] {
      78.0,    78.0,    78.0,
      0.0,     0.0,     78.0,
      69.0,    56.0,    0.0};
   QTextEdit edit;
   setHtml(&edit, toTable(std::begin(table), std::end(table), 3,
                          [](double arg){ return QString::number(arg, 'f', 1); },
                          "width=\"100%\""));
   edit.setReadOnly(true);
   edit.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```